# Can I move stackable trait logic to parent?

Tags: scala, traits

I'm not sure is it possible or I'm asking the wrong question here. Let's say if I have something like

```
trait Parent {
    def foo : String = " Parent "
}

trait Child1 extends Parent {
    override def foo : String = super.foo + " Child 1 "
}

trait Child2 extends Parent {
    override def foo : String = super.foo + " Child 2 "
}
```

and use it like

```
class ChildGroup extends Child1 with Child2
(new ChildGroup).foo
```

the result as expected be `" Parent  Child 1  Child 2 "`

but I found it hard to maintain, especially when someone else use my trait and didn't use it the way I meant

```
trait Child3 extends Parent //<-- not override foo, and no error

trait Child4 extends Parent {
    override def foo : String = " Child 4 " //<-- forget super.foo +
}
```

and use like

```
class ChildGroup extends Child1 with Child2 with Child3 with Child4
(new ChildGroup).foo
```

the result will be just `" Child 4 "` and I don't want that to happen I just want it to always be stack

So It would be nice to move all the logic of stack trait to `Parent`

Is it possible to do that? or there are other option that will force other people to always do `super.foo + x`

Comment: You might be able to force a call to `super` using macros or a compiler plugin, but it's generally not a good idea to do so. Even if you force a call to `super.foo`, there's no guarantee it will be used correctly. It's called _semantic binding_, and it should be avoided, as it requires client code to know the semantics of the code it's implementing--which should be no surprise that it leads to bugs. Perhaps there is a clever way to encapsulate what you want within `Parent`, but it could very well be uglier than the former.

Comment: Agree, I don't want macro nor plugin. Just hoping someone would have acceptable ugly solution

Answer (score 1):

This is Object Oriented question.

you can define parent as :

```
trait Parent{
    public final def f():String= {
              "Parent" +g();
    }
    protected abstract def g():String
}

trait Child extends Parent{
    def g()= "Child"
}
```

enforcing parent functionality to run firstly before single child. if you have multiple children and you want to apply all of those functionality when calling to one function, I think it's abusive to use mixin technique like that, this is not the purpose for this technique (adding functionality).

If you would like to add functionality to a function please take a look at the ***Decorator*** design pattern.

regards `trait Child3 extends Parent //<-- not override foo, and no error` it is not possible using reular coding. you can define macro, but I would not suggest it because it's experimental which means it can be removed from the scala sdk.